# php exit from an inner function

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function for creating post. Before save the new post, there is a hook for manipulating data before save:

```
function save(){
  $data = apply_filters('data_before_save',array(....));
  $post_id = wp_insert_post( $data );
  return $post_id;
}
```

Now I am adding stuffs to the $data:

```
add_filter('data_before_save','conditional_save',10,1 );
function conditional_save( $data ){
  //...some stuffs
  if( $data['x']== $blabla ){
     wp_safe_redirect( $link);
     exit();
  }else{
    $data['x'] = $x;
  }
  return $data;
}
```

Will the `function save` be exited by the `function conditional_save` before the line `save_post` ? 
I don't want return any data if condition meet. I tried my code, it seems works-- redirected and didn't create new post. But I want to make sure the `function save` is really stopped running.

Comment: why don't you give it a try?

Comment: Why don't you take a look at **[the docs](http://ca1.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)**?

Comment: @jcsanyi I have mentioned in my ans

Comment: Sorry, I got confused by the function brackets...

Comment: simple answer.... **nope**

Comment: `exit` will immediately stop all script execution. No further code will be run - meaning nothing will be saved or output to the browser.

Comment: just to clarify, you should return `true/false` on insertion/not insertion so that you know when post was added and when it wasn't. exiting will make it ambiguous.

Comment: @jcsanyi , the docs does not mention how to exit from outside a function.

Comment: @itachi , the save function is in another person's plugin, I can't modify it directly. I can only do things and hook onto it.

Comment: @Jenny exit doesn't care if it's in a function. It will stop the entire script, regardless of which functions you're in the middle of. If you just want to get out of the current function, you want `return` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`exit()` will abruptly halt all execution of the code. 
Its not usually a good idea.

Make use of **FLAGS** instead.

EDIT :

**FLAG** is not a reserved keyword.
Just set a `var` to true/false on your conditional save, check for the flag on your `save()`. Depends on the result of the `var` you can restrict what to do and what not to.

Comment: I can't modify the function save directly, it's another person's plugin.